# AS3: BitmapData.draw with alpha and blendmode has incorrect result

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, transparency, bitmapdata

I have a `sprite` that contains overlapping `shape`s. The sprite itself will have it's alpha set to .5, so I have to set the sprite's `blendmode` to "layer" to keep the overlapping parts from looking transparent with each other. In this screenshot taken from [here](http://www.zedia.net/2008/blendmodelayer-a-must-when-changing-alpha-of-a-displayobject-containing-other-displayobject/), it's supposed to look like the one on the right.

[image]

Now I want to `draw` a `bitmapData` from my sprite, but I can't get the resulting bitmap to look like the image on the right. It ends up looking like the image in the middle.

```
spriteBMD.draw(mySprite,null,mySprite.transform.colorTransform,"layer");
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just a wild guess. Try putting it into container and drawing container, not the target sprite.

Answer (score 1):

I have some thoughts about the root cause, but anyway here how it works:

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.BlendMode;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;

var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mc.width, mc.height);
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);

var sourceTransform:ColorTransform = mc.transform.colorTransform;
var bmdTransfrom:ColorTransform;

if(mc.blendMode == BlendMode.NORMAL)
{
    bmdTransfrom = sourceTransform;
}else
{
    bitmap.transform.colorTransform = sourceTransform;
}

bmd.draw(mc, null, bmdTransfrom, mc.blendMode);

addChild(bitmap);
```